# PG sql query to order by formatted date in descending order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to sort monthname and year in a descending order.
The date column in the table is as follows

```
orderdate
----------
2020-12-15
2021-01-15
2021-02-15
2021-02-20
2021-03-21
2021-03-29
2021-04-15
```

The expected results is

```
monthName
-----------
April 2021
March 2021
February 2021
January 2021
December 2020
```

I tried this query

```
select distinct to_char(orderdate::date,'FMMonth YYYY') as monthName from table 
order by to_char(orderdate::date,'FMMonth YYYY') desc;
```

The above query gives me the output as

```
monthName
-----------
March 2021
January 2021
February 2021
December 2020
April 2021
```

How do I get the expected output from the query.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are trying to sort by string, so you get alphabetical order. What you should do:

- Order by year and month
- Then format date the way you want

Try this one:

```
select to_char(trunc_date,'FMMonth YYYY') from
(
    select distinct date_trunc('month', orderdate) as trunc_date from table order by trunc_date desc
) as cte
```

Comment: I tried this 
`select to_char(orderdate::date,'FMMonth YYYY') as monthname from tablename where group by monthname order by min(monthname) desc;`

This also gave me the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

you should order by year first, then month as month number:

```
select distinct to_char(orderdate::date,'FMMonth YYYY') as monthName from table 
order by to_char(orderdate::date,'YYYY MM') desc;
```

sorry i'm not familiar with psql enough to know the date-format, i just guessed that MM is two-digit month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `orderdate` contains formatted text (which is a bad idea BTW) then

```sql
select to_char(omonth, 'FMMonth YYYY') "monthName"
from (select distinct to_date(orderdate, 'yyyy-mm') omonth from the_table) t 
order by omonth desc;
```

If `orderdate`'s type is `date` then

```sql
select to_char(omonth, 'FMMonth YYYY') "monthName"
from (select distinct date_trunc('month', orderdate) omonth from the_table) t 
order by omonth desc;
```